# Create long list in R

Tags: r, list

I want to create a list in R that has 81 elements each of which is a length 1 vector with the value value `NA`. I tried

```
list = list(rep(NA, 81))
```

But this create a list of 1 element of length 81. I also tried:

```
list = list(rep(list(NA),81))
```

But this returns a list of 81 elements which are nested lists not vectors. My desired output is something like this:

```
> list
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA
.
.
.
[[81]]
[1] NA
```

Comment: `as.list(rep(NA, 81))` or `replicate(81, NA, simplify=FALSE)` (more likely the first ... the use of `replicate` has considerations that may not be a factor for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, try this line of code here

```
rep(list(NA),81)
```